# How do I keep sets of images as separate galleries with jQuery Colorbox?

Tags: jquery, colorbox, magento-1.5, image-gallery

I have colorbox installed on Magento to serve as image galleries for specific product lines. Now, when I view the colorbox, I see all of the images in one gallery. For instance:

Gallery 1 (10 images) on Page A
Gallery 2 (10 images) on Page B

On either Page A or Page B, I see 20 images within the Colorbox Image Gallery.

How do I make Colorbox only show the 10 images that correspond on Page A?

Answer (score 1):

Images are grouped by either the anchor elements rel attribute, or by selecting just the elements you want grouped together and give colorbox a rel property for them.  Example:

```
$('#pageA a.photo').colorbox({rel: 'pageA'});
```